# Why truncation error diverges if step is too small for $(x+1)^3(x-2)^2?$

Tags: numerical-methods

Why truncation error diverges if step is too small for $(x+1)^3(x-2)^2?$ I have calculated the *integral* with trapezium rule on interval $[-1, 2].$

[image]

EDIT:
I publish needed code to test, maybe it will help with answer.

```
 +Integration   
   Trapezoidal.m
   Test.m
```

**Trapezoidal.m**

```
function Int = Trapezoidal(f, a, b, h)
    n = (b - a) / h;
    y = f(linspace(a, b, n + 1));
    sum_y = sum(y) - 0.5 * (y(1) + y(end));
    Int = sum_y * h;
end
```

**Test.m**

```
function Test(f, a, b)
    h = (ones(1,8)*10).^(-(0:7));

    area = integral(f, a, b);

    trapezoidal = arrayfun(@(h_) (abs(area - Integration.Trapezoidal(f, a, b, h_))), h);

    figure
    loglog(h, trapezoidal, 'r+');
    legend('trapezoidal', 'Location', 'northwest');
    xlabel('h');
    ylabel('truncation error');
end
```

Comman window

```
f1 = @(x)(x+1).^3.*(x-2).^2
Integration.Test(f1, -1, 2)
```

Comment: `sum_y = sum(y) - 0.5 * (y(1) + y(end));` What is `end`?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Last index of array

Comment: Ok, where `end` defined?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/end.html

Comment: The error you observe is not the truncation error only, but round-off error also. While for your integral this error cannot be less than $\sim 10^{-15}$,  the actual error of $10^{-12}$ shows that `sum(y)` is not very stable with respect to that kind of errors.